# Qual a diferença entre SaveChanges e SubmitChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Dentro do contexto *Entity Framework* qual a diferença entre `SaveChanges` e `SubmitChanges`?

Quando devo usar um ou o outro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [SaveChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savechanges?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0#System_Data_Objects_ObjectContext_SaveChanges)

É transacional por completo. Se houver uma falha que impeça a persistência de todos os dados tudo volta ao estado original (*rolllback*) e tem que começar do zero.

## [SubmitChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0#overloads)

Faz o mesmo sem modificar o `DataContext`. O código terá quer fazer qualquer ajuste nele manualmente. A transação não contempla o que está na memória. Dá flexibilidade de como proceder com esses dados, se devem ser descartados, modificados, ou só tentar de novo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md)

Answer (score 10):

**[`SaveChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx)**: Persiste todas as atualizações na fonte de dados e redefine o controle de alterações no contexto do objeto. Opera em uma transação. Ele reverterá a transação e lançará uma exceção se algum dos objetos sujos de `ObjectStateEntry` não podem ser persistentes.

**[`SubmitChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges(v=vs.110).aspx)**: Calcula o conjunto de objetos modificados para ser inserida, atualizada ou excluída e executa os comandos apropriados para implementar as alterações no banco de dados. Inicia uma transação e será revertida se ocorrer uma exceção enquanto `SubmitChanges` está em execução. No entanto, isso não reverte as alterações na memória ou controlada pelo `DataContext`; essas alterações precisará ser revertidas manualmente. Você pode iniciar com uma nova instância do `DataContext` se as alterações na memória devem ser descartados.